# spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.javax.cache.uri property set with Jetty server

Tags: spring-boot, jetty, ehcache

I have an error in a spring-boot + jetty app when trying to set **spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.javax.cache.uri** property value at *application.properties* file.

When I do:

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.javax.cache.uri=classpath:/ehcache.xml`

The error is:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cache provider not started`
...
`Caused by: javax.cache.CacheException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: classpath`

Otherwise, if I use a tomcat server as dependency everything works fine.

How can I set the property value in a right way using jetty?

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution using SpEL:

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.javax.cache.uri=${ new org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource("/ehcache.xml").getURI().toString()}`